# Meaning of "hit off" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've already read this sentence and I don't know the exactly sense.

> Married people don't always hit it off.

I think maybe it means married people aren't always happy. Am I wrong?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily discovered with a dictionary, provided you know to look up the whole phrase: [hit it off](http://www.onelook.com/?w=hit+it+off&ls=a).

The phrase means *to have a good relationship with; to get along well together*.

Although it's roughly the same as *being happy*, I'd say it's more a matter of *being compatible*.

The whole sentence means that, after young lovers get married, they often find that they find themselves bickering with each other more than they enjoy each others' company. I'd paraphrase it as:

> Married people don't always have a harmonious relationship.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find the expression in my dictionary.

Comment: But I think it's not an appropriate use (with married people).  To me, *hit it off* is something that happens when two people first meet and describes their first encounter.  Married people are definitely beyond that point in their relationships.

Comment: @María - I understand that phrasal verbs can be hard to find in the dictionary, and therefore can be hard to interpret. Verbs used in conjunction with _out, up, on,_ or _off_ often have different meanings, and are can be listed separately. This can make these words hard to [look up](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/look-up).

Comment: @Jim - That's a good point, and I agree with it. That said, I can imagine contexts where the phrase could be used in the context of marriage. (For example: _Many people meet their future spouse using an online dating service. After a relatively brief courtship, they get married, only to find that they are not hitting it off._) But you're right in pointing out that the phrase is more likely to be used when talking about the early stages of a relationship (e.g., _I took Jill out on two or three dates, but we never really hit it off_).

Comment: @Jim Also, arranged marriages... sometimes the wedding is the first time they get to meet each other.

Comment: @Jim: the world would be great if all married couples were in a relationship and had established compatibility before they are tied together for life. Sadly, for many people, marriage is a decision they have no say in.

Comment: I , for whatever it's worth as a non-native English speaker was having difficulty establishing exactly whether the phrase "hit it off" applies to the early stages of a relationship or if it can also describe "getting along" later in a relationship timeline. Based on the definitions available in many dictionaries I looked up it seems like both of these usages might be allowed although I never heard it being used for the latter in a real life context.